# Given an equation with trigonometric roots $\tan a$ and $\cot a$, determine $\sin a + \cos a$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, roots

**Question**: Given that $\tan a$ and $\cot a$ are two real roots of the equation $x^2 + k^2 - kx - 3 = 0$, and $3\pi < a < \frac{7\pi}{2}$, find the value of $\sin a + \cos a$.

My solution can be found below in the answers section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**My solution:**

First realize that the range for $a$ can be simplified to $\pi < a < \frac{3\pi}{2}$.

Since $\tan a$ and $\cot a$ have a product of $1$, using Vieta's formula, $k^2 - 3 = 1 \Longrightarrow k = \pm 2$.

So, either $x^2 + 2x + 1 = 0$ or $x^2 - 2x + 1 = 0$.

Hence, $x = \pm 1$.

So, using the fact that $\tan a$ and $\cot a$ have a product of $1$, either $\tan a = \cot a = 1$ or $\tan a = \cot a = -1$.

If $\tan a = \cot a = 1$ $\Longrightarrow \sin a = \cos a.$ This would make $a = \frac{\pi}{4}$. However, this does not fit within the range for $a$.

So, $\tan a = \cot a = -1 \Longrightarrow \sin a = -\cos a.$ This would make $a = \frac{5\pi}{4}$. This fits within the range for $a$.

However, we must read the problem carefully as it asks for the value of $\sin a + \cos a$ and not just the value of $a$ itself.

So, the answer is $-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} = \boxed{-\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Are you asking people to check your work, or are you showcasing your solution?

Comment: @Joe I'm showcasing my solution because when you create a question, there's an option for a Q and A style.

Comment: @Iamaperson everything seems to be correct but you must report final answer as $-\sqrt 2$

Comment: @Iamaperson yes but what is your question?

Comment: @LalitTolani ohhh I forgot about that thanks :)

Comment: @bigbang it is what Lalit Tolani said. I forgot that I was supposed to do sin a + cos a, which is why I got the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in the given range $\sin a,\cos a<0$

$\implies y=\sin a+\cos a<0$

Now $k=\tan a+\cot a=\dfrac1{\sin a\cos a}>0$

Again $k^2-3=\tan a\cot a=1\implies k=?$ as $k>0$

Now $$y^2=1+\dfrac2k$$

Finally use the fact $y<0$

Comment: Thanks for the solution!